# JRoute not working correctly for menu link

Tags: joomla1.5, sef

I am using Joomla 1.5 and enabled `SEF`. It works fine for other urls but some links display "page ok" only. It does not show any page content. Why does it show "page ok"
only. How should I avoid this?

Menu is not working for Joomla SEF

```
<li><a href="<?php  echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=28'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/animal/images/shop.jpg" width="101" height="31" /></a></li>
<li><a href="<?php  echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=7'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/animal/images/donationsBut.jpg" width="100" height="31" /></a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_aicontactsafe&view=message&layout=message&pf=1&Itemid=8'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/animal/images/contactBut.jpg" width="101" height="31" /></a></li>
```

The url shown for the menu is http://www.xxx/donations and it does not have any content in page.

if I remove the /itemid it displays the content and the url is component/content/article/7